# Setup project for windows service with multiple instances

Tags: .net, deployment, setup-project

I have written a windows service and have created a setup project to install it. I also add custom action for select service name during a setup process. It works fine if install only one instance of the service. However, in some deployments, we will need to install multiple instances of the service with different configuration. if I try to install another copy of the service with one already installed, it thinks I want to repair or remove the previous copy.

Can the setup project be made to accommodate installing multiple instances of an application ?

Comment: "we will need to install multiple instances of the service with different". Different what?

Comment: different configuration and different name

Comment: Are you just running the same .msi multiple times with different parameters?

Comment: I plan use different parameters but setup allowed me only repair or remove the previous installation when I run it second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments indicate that you are trying to install multiple instances of a product from a single .msi by specifying different parameters to msiexec. This will not work.  As you have discovered, Windows Installer regards your .msi as being a single product and won't allow it to be installed multiple times.

What you need to do is to get your .msi to install all the different service instances at once. You'll need to specify all the different configuration options for each service in the call to msiexec, and effectively loop inside your installer.

Comment: I cannot use this solution because sometimes I have need to install second instance after a some time

Comment: then you'll need to do that as modify action

Comment: I'm not sure if that will allow me to two different installation points

Comment: why would you install the same executable file to two different locations.

Comment: In my system each executable file have one configuration file I want be able create another service with different configuration

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am also have same scenario as mentioned by davidb. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue as the OP. I found this article describing how to accomplish the installation of multiple services using the dotNet installutil.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx

If I understand correctly, this is an alternative to using an MSI. In my circumstance, that's acceptable, so I'm going to give this a try. I guess if I get it working, I could always create an MSI which just runs the installutil.exe commandline.

Wish me luck.